# How to scale up the good variable for minimization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, minimization

I am using quasi newton algorithm(Numerical recipes) for minimization in which i have to assign the variables. I selected some variables but i do not know those are good scale up variables. Is anybody knows how to scale up the good variable. 
I have a c-code with function(f(x)) and its gradients and also quasi newton algorithm code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in most cases you don't need scaling. But if you have the case of parameters differing by orders of magnitude, scaling maybe worthwhile. In that case I would scale the parameters by the first guess. E.g. if you can specify the starting point and it is not terribly far off of the expected true value, it should also provide reasonable scaling.

Comment: I got the function value is around 900. Could you tell what i should modify.

Comment: scaling doesn't depend on function value. Scaling depends what are the values of the *arguments* of the function.
Overall if you really want an answer you need to demonstrate that you have the problem, otherwise your question is too abstract and not very meaningful